# Flex4 calendar

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, calendar

I am looking for a Flex4 calendar with source code.

Ready to pay for it also.

I do not want to use the IBM ilog calendar, that i was using before for my website.

Any suggestions.

Thanks
~Z~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out our [Flex Calendar Component](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=15).  Free developer editions are available for you to test.  The component supports Flex 3 and up; and we provide a version specifically for Flex 4.

Really it depends what you're looking for though.

I think ours is the most flexible implementation out there; with everything visual, such as the day components, implemented as renderers, thus giving you complete control over display and functionality.

However, our component is not going to be a replacement for "Google Calendar" as is.

We're always an e-mail away for [support purposes](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ContactForm).

Comment: +1.  We compared 3 commercial calendar controls and one open-source control.  We came to the conclusion that the Flextras calendar was the best for us.  It wasn't the most shiny calendar out of the box... but it is the most extensible.  Everything is skinnable and you get access to tons of events.  For $500 (including source code), it was a winner for us.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Flextras, there's also one in IBM's iLog Elixir. I believe it's much more expensive. Examples of Elixir and Flextras are in Tour De Flex I believe.

Comment: +1 for the mention of me; yes Flextras should be in Tour De Flex as should IBM iLog Elixir.  I will point out the original poster, explicitly stated he didn't want to use iLog.  He didn't elaborate, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this one? http://www.keepcore.com/composants-flex/flex-calendar-component.html

Comment: I have checked this one!! Thanks